# PHP random image script troubles

Tags: php, html

Hi  I create random php image script but it does not work. It echos the links but it does not include the random variable.

```
$f_contents = file ("random1.txt", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$link = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)]; /*Line 6*/


echo '<a href="http://www.site.com/view.php?t='.$link.'"><img src="http://www.site.com/images/'.$link.'.jpg" /></a>';
echo "</center>";
```

Comment: Do you have any errors / warnings in your log files?

Comment: How do we know that $f_contents has any content?

Comment: What 'random' variable are you referring to? there are only two variables, in your code.

Comment: @SlyRaskal random1.txt is (supposedly) a text file of those elements and one is picked at random using array_rand.

Comment: I understand that, but he states that the link is echoed, but it doesn't include the 'random' variable.  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SlyRaskal The random variable is `$link`, the link is in the echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function [array_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns an array.  So you need to change this:

```
$link = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)]; /*Line 6*/
```

Into this:

```
$link = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)[0]]; /*Line 6*/
```

Or perhaps this instead:

```
$rand_value = array_rand($f_contents);
$link = $f_contents[$rand_value[0]]; /*Line 6*/
```

I would also suggest error proofing your code to be like this to always check if `$f_contents` has content or not:

```
$f_contents = file ("random1.txt", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
if (!empty($f_contents)) {
  $rand_value = array_rand($f_contents);
  $link = $f_contents[$rand_value[0]]; /*Line 6*/

  echo '<a href="http://www.site.com/view.php?t='.$link.'"><img src="http://www.site.com/images/'.$link.'.jpg" /></a>';
  echo "</center>";
}
```

**EDIT** Also `array_rand` accepts a second argument connected to how many random items are returned. So if you set that value to `1` then it will return a string instead of an array so the code would look like this:

```
$f_contents = file ("random1.txt", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
if (!empty($f_contents)) {
  $rand_value = array_rand($f_contents, 1);
  $link = $f_contents[$rand_value]; /*Line 6*/

  echo '<a href="http://www.site.com/view.php?t='.$link.'"><img src="http://www.site.com/images/'.$link.'.jpg" /></a>';
  echo "</center>";
}
```

Comment: You could also set the second argument in array_rand to 1. "When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. "